# could we use tidal forces H.E.P for energy on ceres asteroid

Tags: tidal-forces, habitable-zone

to make energy could we use the tidal forces in the water under Ceres surface?

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the strength of the tidal forces on Ceres from The Sun, Jupiter, Mars, Earth, etc?  You should be able to look up the formulas for calculating tidal strength.  How deep is the supterranean water?  It might be a very big project to did deep enough to install a tidal power station, and possibly it would be less trouble to a fusion power generator on the surface.

Comment: What tidal forces?

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing up Ceres with one of Jupiter's big moons, like Europa?

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff that sounds plausible, I get all these salty ice balls mixed up

Answer (score 2):

At the distance of Earth, solar tides are half as high as lunar tides, and with the two together, tidal power is only of limited use, and only in locations where the geography gives it additional advantages.

Tidal forces scale in direct proportion to radius and in inverse proportion to the *cube* of distance. Ceres is less than 1/13th the size of Earth and gets nearly 3 times as far from the sun. It won't have any lunar tides at all, and the solar tides will be 1/360th as strong. Overall, the tides on Earth are about a thousand times stronger. The tides on Ceres will not be a useful source of power.